# How to stretch background color

Tags: html, css

I had taken and found the following code for a navigation menu that I was interested in using however just had a quick question if anyone can help. What I am wanting to take and see if it was possible, was to take and make the color stretch to the top of the screen to fill the gap in the following code. Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance. Any  questions let me know. Area in question is in the header area where it says "Some Text Here" wanting to go to the top of screen if possible for the color.

[image]

Here is the code

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/labs.css">
        <title>Site Title Here</title>
        <script>
            var script = function(src) {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.async = true;
                e.src = src;
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
            };
    
            var style = function(css) {
                var e = document.createElement('style');
                if (e.styleSheet) {
                    e.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                } else {
                    e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
                }
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
            }
    
            var toggleDisplay = function(el, display, class_el) {
                var EL = document.querySelector(el);
                if (EL.style.display == display) {
                    EL.style.display = "none";
                    if (class_el) EL.classList.add(class_el);
                } else {
                    EL.style.display = display;
                    if (class_el) EL.classList.add(class_el);
                }
            };
    
            if (!showAds) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var w = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
                    if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
                        ga('send', 'event', 'Adblock', 'Yes', {
                            'nonInteraction': 1
                        });
                    } else if (typeof _gaq !== 'undefined') {
                        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Adblock', 'Yes', undefined, undefined, true]);
                    }
    
                    var ab_a = document.createElement("div"),
                        w_p = w.parentNode;
                    w_p.classList.add("ab-active");
                    ab_a.setAttribute("class", "ab-alert");
                    w_p.parentNode.insertBefore(ab_a, w_p);
                    ab_a.innerHTML = '<p>I never intend to spoil your experience here, but this is important. I want to share with you that this website exists totally because of adverts money.</p><p>If you whitelist my website in your adblocker software, I won\'t show you more than two Google ads per page, and no popups. It\'s a promise.</p><p>Thanks for your patience :-)</p><p class="small" style="opacity: .75">This message disappears by itself in 15 seconds.</p>';
    
                    var ab = document.querySelector(".ab-alert");
    
                    document.documentElement.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", "return false");
    
                    style('.ab-alert{box-sizing:border-box;line-height:1.75}.site-wrapper{transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;}.ab-active{ opacity: .0125; pointer-events: none;position:fixed;width:100%;}.ab-alert,.ab-active{user-select:none;}.ab-alert{opacity: 1;transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;font-size: 15px;position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%); width: 100%;max-width: 450px; background-color: white; padding: 2.5em}');
    
                    setInterval(function() {
                        ab.style.opacity = "0";
                        ab.remove();
                        w_p.classList.remove("ab-active");
                        document.documentElement.removeAttribute("oncontextmenu");
                    }, 15000);
                }, 1000);
            }
    
            script("//s3.buysellads.com/ac/bsa.js");
    
        </script>
        <!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v5.9.1 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://w3bits.com/labs/css-responsive-nav/" />
        <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="A CSS-only Touch-friendly Navigation Menu - W3Bits" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Navigation ▾ Sample Dropdown ▾ ▾ Item 1.1 Item 1.2 Item 1.3 Item 1.4 2-level DD ▾ ▾ Item 2.1 Item 2.2 ▸ ▾ Item 2.2.1 Item 2.2.2 Item 2.2.3 Item 2.3 Multiple Levels ▾ ▾ 3.1 ▸ ▾ 3.1.1 3.1.2 3.1.3 3.1.4 3.2 ▸ ▾ 3.2.1 3.2.2 3.2.3 3.3 ▸ ▾ 3.3.1 3.3.2 3.2.2 &hellip;" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://w3bits.com/labs/css-responsive-nav/" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="W3Bits" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="Navigation ▾ Sample Dropdown ▾ ▾ Item 1.1 Item 1.2 Item 1.3 Item 1.4 2-level DD ▾ ▾ Item 2.1 Item 2.2 ▸ ▾ Item 2.2.1 Item 2.2.2 Item 2.2.3 Item 2.3 Multiple Levels ▾ ▾ 3.1 ▸ ▾ 3.1.1 3.1.2 3.1.3 3.1.4 3.2 ▸ ▾ 3.2.1 3.2.2 3.2.3 3.3 ▸ ▾ 3.3.1 3.3.2 3.2.2 [&hellip;]" />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="A CSS-only Touch-friendly Navigation Menu - W3Bits" />
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@w3bits_" />
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@w3bits_" />
        <script type='application/ld+json'>
            {
                "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
                "@type": "WebSite",
                "@id": "#website",
                "url": "http:\/\/w3bits.com\/",
                "name": "W3Bits",
                "potentialAction": {
                    "@type": "SearchAction",
                    "target": "http:\/\/w3bits.com\/?s={search_term_string}",
                    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
                }
            }
    
        </script>
        <!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->
    
        <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
        <link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://w3bits.com/wp-json/' />
        <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://w3bits.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
        <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://w3bits.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" />
        <link rel='shortlink' href='http://w3bits.com/?p=2474' />
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://w3bits.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fw3bits.com%2Flabs%2Fcss-responsive-nav%2F" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://w3bits.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fw3bits.com%2Flabs%2Fcss-responsive-nav%2F&#038;format=xml" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://w3bits.com/files/css/css-responsive-nav.css">
    </head>
    
    <body class="labs-template-default single single-labs postid-2474">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="bup" id="bup">
                    <style>
                        .w3bits-labs {
                            width: 468px;
                            height: 60px;
                            margin: 1.5em 0 0
                        }
    
                        @media(min-width: 728px) {
                            .w3bits-labs {
                                width: 728px !important;
                                height: 90px !important;
                            }
                        }
    
                        @media(max-width:727px) and (min-width: 468px) {
                            .w3bits-labs {
                                width: 468px !important;
                                height: 60px !important;
                            }
                        }
    
                        @media(max-width: 467px) and (min-width: 234px) {
                            .w3bits-labs {
                                width: 234px !important;
                                height: 60px !important;
                            }
                        }
    
                    </style>
                    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                    <!-- W3Bits Labs -->
                    <ins class="adsbygoogle w3bits-labs" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1581655830066906" data-ad-slot="9749450056" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                    <script>
                        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    
                    </script>
                </div>
    
                <div style="background:#0099cc; font-size:22px; text-align:center; color:#000; font-weight:bold; height:auto; padding-top:50px;">Some Text Here !!</div>
                <div id="wrap">
    
    
                    <nav id="menu">
                        <label for="tm" id="toggle-menu">Navigation Menu <span class="drop-icon">▾</span></label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="tm">
                        <ul class="main-menu cf">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown
            <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm0">▾</label>
          </a>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="sm0">
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 1.4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">2-level DD 
            <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm1">▾</label>
          </a>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="sm1">
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 2.2
                <span class="drop-icon">▸</span>
                <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm2">▾</label>
              </a>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm2">
                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2.1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2.2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2.3</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Item 2.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Multiple Levels
            <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm3">▾</label>
        </a>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="sm3">
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="">3.1
            <span class="drop-icon">▸</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm4">▾</label>
          </a>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm4">
                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li><a href="">3.1.1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.1.2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.1.3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.1.4</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="">3.2
            <span class="drop-icon">▸</span>
            <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm5">▾</label>
          </a>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm5">
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li><a href="">3.2.1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.2.2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.2.3</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="">3.3
              <span class="drop-icon">▸</span>
                <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm6">▾</label>
              </a>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="sm6">
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li><a href="">3.3.1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.3.2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.2.2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.3.4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">3.3.5</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sample #2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another DD
              <span class="drop-icon">▾</span>
                <label title="Toggle Drop-down" class="drop-icon" for="sm8">▾</label>
              </a>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="sm8">
                                </a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="">4.1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">4.2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">4.2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">4.4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <nav class="cf lab-nav lab-nav--fixed lab-nav--bottom  lab-nav--light">
                    <a href="http://w3bits.com/css-responsive-nav-menu/" title="Back to the article" class="lab-article-link">
            <svg class="icon icon-right-open icon-reverse">
                <use xlink:href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-right-open"></use>
            </svg><span> Article</span></a>
                    <ul class="lab-share">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://w3bits.com/css-responsive-nav-menu/" title="Share on Facebook">
                    <svg class="icon icon-facebook">
                        <use xlink:href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-facebook"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
     -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http://w3bits.com/css-responsive-nav-menu/&text=$article_title&url=http://w3bits.com/css-responsive-nav-menu/&via=w3bits_" title="Tweet">
                    <svg class="icon icon-twitter">
                        <use xlink:href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-twitter"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
     -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://w3bits.com/css-responsive-nav-menu/" title="Share on Google+">
                    <svg class="icon icon-gplus">
                        <use xlink:href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-gplus"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
     -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void((function(d){var%20e=d.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);d.body.appendChild(e)})(document));" title="Pin-it on Pinterest">
                    <svg class="icon icon-pinterest">
                        <use xlink:href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-pinterest"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                        </li>
                        <!--
     -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?url=http://w3bits.com/css-responsive-nav-menu/" class="share-link" rel="external nofollow" title="Share the love" target="_blank">
                    <svg class="icon icon-share">
                        <use xlink:href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-share"></use>
                    </svg><span></span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
    
                <a href="http://w3bits.com/follow/" class="lab-follow lab-follow--light"><svg class="icon icon-plus"><use xlink:href="http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/img/icons.svg#icon-plus"></use></svg> Follow</a>
    
                <script>
                    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                        i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                        a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                        a.async = 1;
                        a.src = g;
                        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
                    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
                    ga('create', 'UA-10703354-8', 'w3bits.com');
                    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
                    ga('send', 'pageview');
                    var toggle_menu = document.querySelector("#toggle_menu"),
                        toggle_search = document.querySelector("#toggle_search");
                    if (toggle_menu) {
                        toggle_menu.addEventListener("click", function() {
                            toggleDisplay("#main-nav", "block", false);
                            toggle_menu.classList.toggle("active");
                            toggle_menu.children[0].classList.toggle("icon-close");
                        }, false);
                    }
                    if (toggle_search) {
                        toggle_search.addEventListener("click", function() {
                            toggleDisplay("#search", "block", false);
                            toggle_search.classList.toggle("active");
                            toggle_search.children[0].classList.toggle("icon-close");
                        }, false);
                    }
    
                </script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='http://w3bits.com/wp-content/themes/bits-v2/assets/js/prettify.js'></script>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    prettyPrint()
    
                </script>
            </div>
    
    
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Please add screenshot...

Comment: Not sure how to do it have not tried anything other then someone suggested to try adding <div style="background:#0099cc; font-size:22px; text-align:center; color:#000; font-weight:bold; height:auto; padding-top:50px;width:100%;overflow:hidden;">Some Text Here !!</div but it did not do anything

Comment: took and added a screen shot of what it looks like now and trying to stretch the color to the top like shown in the screen shot but the <div style="background:#0099cc; font-size:22px; text-align:center; color:#000; font-weight:bold; height:auto; padding-top:50px;width:100%;overflow:hidden;">Some Text Here !!</div did not take and do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is google ads thats not loading at the very top and a div has a margin.

Do the following to get rid of the space above the site/page

1.Look for and delete the following:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle w3bits-labs" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1581655830066906" data-ad-slot="9749450056" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

2.Next your div with bup class and id has a margin. Remove the margin and you are good to go:

```
.bup {
    margin: 0 auto 2.5em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

`.bup` can found in `labs.css`

Comment: Thank's a lot that took and helped a lot, still a little gap at the top but it is a lot better then before

Comment: Body has margin and padding set to zero?

Comment: OK I took and played around with a few things and got it to take and be even with the top of the page and stretch the menu out across the page top. YThanks again for the help..:)

Comment: Select this as chosen answer if it is please

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div style="background:#0099cc; font-size:22px; text-align:center; color:#000; font-weight:bold; height:auto; padding-top:50px;width:100%;overflow:hidden;">Some Text Here !!</div>
```

Let me know how it goes.

See it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/duqrqLpg/1/

Comment: didn't work color:#000; font-weight:bold; height:auto; padding-top:50px;width:100%;overflow:hidden;

Comment: I took and added a screenshot of the area a the top that i am trying to fill

Comment: Where can I see the screenshot? May I am not clear what issues you are having currently. I sure there is a solution.

Comment: Do you want the text Some Text Here !! to be above the color box or inside the box but in the middle of the color box?

Comment: I don't know why the image did not take, but just took and added a link to the question to the image I uploaded to a server. Here is the direct link to the image https://thebookshelf.neocities.org/Capture.PNG  Trying to take and move everything up to the top of the grey area in the screen shot, which would take and be the top of the screen. As of right now it sits in the browser window as shown in the screen shot.  The goal is to move the entire thing flush with the top of the grey box.